# Does corrective eye surgery for affect the ability to focus similar to corrective lenses?

Tags: eye, surgery, eye-strain, lasik

If corrective lenses adjust the point at which the eyes focus and, for a strong correction, inhibit the ability to focus at the opposing distance, will corrective eye surgery affect vision in the same way?

For example, will corrective eye surgery for someone with extreme nearsightedness reduce or inhibit their ability to focus on objects up close?

I am wondering if such an extreme correction would require someone to trade their lenses for nearsightedness (pre-surgery) for farsighted lenses, as they would lose their ability to focus up close?

Comment: I used to be extremely near sighted. around 6 years ago I had eye correction surgery the Dr adjusted the laser to correy my vision so that I can see far and near at that time. I'm just now starting to get a lil harder to read up close. In a couple years I'll probably need reading glasses. This is normal and due to age.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Was this Monovision LASIK?

Comment: I had Lasek where they removed a small layer of cornea with an acid. Then they laser cut a computer generated proscription. Was able to see better right away however I had a 2 week recovery time at home with more than 5 medicated drops. Then prob 2 month recovery to 20/20 and took a year till fully recovered to 20/10